# Express.js Router not working even in a simple case on my server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, routes

I have a problem with use `express.Router()`. It wasn`t working in my application to server JSON from a MongoDB so i tried to do the same on the easiest case, but in the request i have 404 Not Found error. What should i do with it ?

**App.js**

```html
// include all modules
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var PageScheme = require('./lib/PageScheme');
//var sendPages = require('./routes/sendPage');
//var serveMain = require('./routes/serveMain');
var testserv = require('./routes/test');
var app = express(); //use express.js as an framework in application

//switch on all features to work with the requests
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies from requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // support encoded bodies from requests

//add reference to directory and next resolve all names of directory to send static files
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'))); 
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/img'));

//this is my route ! 
app.use('/test',testserv);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('generator.html', {
    root: __dirname
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 9000, process.env.IP || '0.0.0.0');
```

**test.js**

```html
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// route some test text.
router.post('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Some text ...');
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I'd recommend to remove all the code except the router, make sure it works and then add the rest of the code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `404` is probably because Express cannot find the route. Are you making your request as `http://.../test/test`? If not that would probably be the problem. When you are defining the route in your `test.js` file, you are giving it a route of `/test` and then in `app.js` your are saying give all my routes in `test.js` a base of `/test`. I would recommend definining the route in `test.js` as:

```
// route some test text.
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Some text ...');
});
module.exports = router;
```

That way, this is your base POST route for the `test.js` module, so you would make the request with `http://.../test/`

Comment: Glad I can help :)